# Excel VBA: Search outlook with Category and Date parameters

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a Macro that can efficiently search a Shared Mailbox in outlook with my desired category and date the email was received.

txtCat will be the category

txtDate is where I will input the date in this format : "mm/dd/yyyy"

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

```
Dim outlookapp
Dim olns As Outlook.Namespace
Dim Fldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olMail As Object
Dim myTasks
Dim myrecipient As Outlook.Recipient
Dim dateString As Long
Dim strfilter As String
Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olns = outlookapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myrecipient = olns.CreateRecipient("Cmaintenancesupport2")
myrecipient.Resolve
Dim strCat As String

'txtCat is the category
'txtDate is the date
Set Fldr = olns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myrecipient, olFolderInbox)

strCat = UserForm1.txtCat.Text

strfilter = "[Categories] = """ & strCat & """"


dateString = CDate(UserForm1.txtDate.Text)

Set myTasks = Fldr.Items.Restrict(strfilter) 'filters the desired category in the SharedDefault Mailbox


Set myTasks = myTasks.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] = '" & Format(dateString, "DDDDD HH:NN") & "'") 'adds another filter by date


For Each olMail In myTasks

olMail.Display

Next



End Sub
```

i set mytasks twice as I am just restructuring this code from a previous project that works (categorized email > filter by days > search subject line) but somehow it is not showing me any results.

What should happen here is after the category filter, it should all already categorized email with the desired date.

Comment: I'd recommend you to start with no filter at all. Do you get emails displayed then? If not then the error is not in the filters. If you get hits, add a filter at a time until you find the error.

Comment: hi peakpeak. but the filter is essential in this case. there are no errors. it is just returning anything.

Comment: That is my point. Do you get **any** return *without* the filters?

Comment: i am not actually sure how it will display anything without the filters as the loop for "olmail.display" is reliant on the filters "for each olmail in mytasks" ... if it adds anything, the code structure is actually derived from another macro that works, the only difference is that the original macro takes the categories and a search string and takes into account the days that passed by from present date.

Comment: The suggested debugging step from peakpeak is to comment out the two restrict statements and see if you get results with `Set myTasks = Fldr.Items`. This will give an indication whether the earlier part of the code does what you think it does.

Comment: ok i removed the set mytasks and without the restrict filters, it displayed all contents in the shared mailbox until outlook crashed due to running out of memory. so i decided to add the first filter, which is to display all emails with a certain category, it works. i decided to remove this filter and add the date filter but for some reason it is not displaying anything. i think the filter for date is not working here, must be the date format syntax? thanks in advance.

Comment: by the way, the format in the outlook client is mm/dd/yyyy. i tried Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy") but still did not work.

Comment: ok i got to make it work now by using the syntax for the date as "Set myTasks = myTasks.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" & Format(dateString, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'")" only issue now is this does not work if i removed the ">". is there a way to edit this so that the "=" would suffice?